# convert textarea of crispy form into rich text editor?

Tags: django, django-forms, html-editor, rich-text-editor, django-crispy-forms

Can anyone tell me the best way to convert a simple textarea of crispy form into a rich html text editor. i tried many time but tinyMCE woks only on normal form not on crispy form. i am new to django help will be appreciated

Comment: Normally, the way I use to create rich text box is using a third-party library in `javascript` that has it's own `css`. This libraries work by doing some small initialization and getting the `textarea` elements in the page and applying it the style. It should work with any from. These ones my be usefull http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/

Comment: problem solved. thanks a million for the help